# Trying to compile a C program with GCC and math.h header

Tags: c, gcc, linker, math.h

So, I'm trying to compile a simple C program in windows environment using GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("hi\n");
    double x = sin(10);
    printf("%lf\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following command to compile:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lm
```

and it gives the following error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sin' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |     double x = sin(10);
      |                ^~~
test.c:3:1: note: include '<math.h>' or provide a declaration of 'sin'
    2 | #include <math.h>
  +++ |+#include <math.h>
    3 |
test.c:6:16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sin' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
    6 |     double x = sin(10);
      |                ^~~
test.c:6:16: note: include '<math.h>' or provide a declaration of 'sin'
```

Note that I declared the `<math.h>` header and link the library with the command `-lm`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have an empty or otherwise bogus file `math.h` somewhere before the standard include directory.  Also note that `%lf` is incorrect: you should just use `%f` in `printf`.

Comment: Your program works for me as is, so I agree with @chqrlie, but just wanted to share with you that if you run `cpp your_file.c` it will tell you which math.h file it's reading (and it's contents).

Comment: do `gcc -H -c test.c` and see which `math.h` is included.